# Python and Unicode

Tags: python, django, unicode

I'm learning Django through the tutorials on their website and I'm running into a weird problem.  At this [step](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api) when I get to the part where I enter the unicode snippets so that

```
>>> Poll.objects.all()
```

will return not this

```
[<Poll: Poll object>]
```

but something like this

```
[<Poll: What's up?>]
```

for some reason the code only works when I copy and paste it in, and not when I type it in.  Any ideas why this is happening?

::

So here is the code that wouldn't format in the comments:

```
from django.db import models

import datetime

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def was_published_today(self):
        return self.pub_date.date() ==datetime.date.today()
    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

Comment: Indentation might be wrong. Show us what you typed in.

Comment: Can you post your Poll model code?

Comment: you may use __unicode__(self) method

Comment: from django.db import models

import datetime

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def was_published_today(self):
     return self.pub_date.date() ==datetime.date.today()
 def __unicode__(self):
  return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
  return self.choice

Comment: from django.db import models

    import datetime

    class Poll(models.Model):
        question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        def was_published_today(self):
         return self.pub_date.date() ==datetime.date.today()
     def __unicode__(self):
      return self.question

    class Choice(models.Model):
        poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
        choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        votes = models.IntegerField()
        def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice

Comment: I'm not getting it to look right here, but it is literally the exact same code in the example and indented in exactly the same way.

Comment: Add the formatted code to your question, it's barely readable in the comments.

Comment: Can you copy and paste your version of the code into your question (just edit the question) so we can see the formatting? It must not be 1:1 if it's working when you copy/paste it from the example.

Comment: That difference may only be due to using different Django versions, and the last one added a custom repr method. Any other problems?

Comment: @Keith: why should it then work when he copy&pastes?

Comment: OIC, it seems the defined object already has the `__unicode__` method.  But what, exactly, is copied and pasted here?

Comment: Oh just select the code and "view selection source" and you'll notice the mixed indentation... I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be caused by mixed tab/space indentation...

Your code pasted in the comment was messed up but I had a look at the HTML source code and found that the lines you typed in (around the `__unicode__` methods, specifically) were indented using mixed tabs/spaces. Maybe you're using an editor where you configured the "tab width" to be 4 so that the a tab indentation level looks the same as 4 spaces. However the python interpreter considers a tab equivalent as 8 spaces (two indent levels). So the lines you typed (or lines with tabs) are wrongly indented.

Here I mark all the tabs in your code with "`<T>`"

```
from django.db import models

import datetime

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def was_published_today(self):
    <T> return self.pub_date.date() ==datetime.date.today()
<T> def __unicode__(self):
<T> <T> return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
<T> <T> return self.choice
```

NEVER mix tabs and spaces, in any language. And in Python we always use 4 spaces to indent as recommended by [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Whatever editor you use, google for how to configure it to automatically expand tabs into 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks, this has been very helpful.  I've pasted the code into the question if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you use TextMate, check Soft Tabs : 4 and use the command Cleanup WhiteSpaces. It worked 4 met!